# When they are/have gone

Tags: grammar, word-choice

The two men leave the room. When they are/have gone, Lisa comes out of the closet where she's been hiding.

Would both "are" and "have" be fine here?

Answer (score 1):

Both are appropriate, although 'are gone' is quite old-fashioned.

Comment: isn't it strange to choose the present to describe this "scene" . Would not it better to use the past     the 2 men left the room . When they had gone, Lisa came out of the closet where she had been hiding